# Validation error: This package contains a StoreManifest.xml file which does not validate against the StoreManifest.xsd schema?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

[image]

This StoreManifest.xml file i am using to upload the package to Windows Store and i am getting the following error.? Anybody had the same experience? Any idea how to resolve?

I am using Window8RTM/VS 2012RTM

Validation error:    This package contains a StoreManifest.xml file which does not validate against the StoreManifest.xsd schema

Answer (score 0):

The blue squiggly lines in the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=` and `xmlns=` sections indicate validation errors. Open the Error List pane and ensure you are viewing the warnings -- they should appear there.

It looks like VS2012 is not able to find the StoreManifest.xsd schema file.

Looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211378.aspx (Schemas for Windows Store apps) I cannot see a StoreManifest schema, only an App pakage manifest. It may be that StoreManifest was for the Alpha/Beta releases of Win8.

If StoreManifest is correct, ensure Visual Studio is looking in the Windows Store Apps/WinRT schema folder for XML schemas (not sure where this is or how to fix this, as I no longer have access to Visual Studio). Once this is done, any further validation errors will have blue squiggles under them and appear as warnings in the error list pane.

Answer (score 0):

This is official [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj730528.aspx) which helped me to solve the problem you are facing.
Hope it helps.